# Reset Photoshop File Associations

Tags: windows, adobe-photoshop, file-management, photoshop-cs6, adobe-cs6

Is there a way to reset Photoshop's file associations without having to reinstall? I had CS6 and CS5.5 installed side by side, and when I uninstalled CS5.5 it removed the file associations.

I tried searching around but everyone seems to have the opposite problem (wanting to remove Photoshop's file associations).

Oh, and just doing Open With > Photoshop and setting that as default doesn't really work right. It displays the wrong icons (which really gets on my nerves).

I am running Windows 8 RP, but the fix should be the same as in Windows 7.

Comment: Re-installing is the proper way to re-associate both the filetypes and their icons.

Answer (score 1):

Open Adobe Bridge and go to Edit | Preferences navigate to File Types Associations and use the Reset to Defautl Associations.